# How do I implement an F# high order function in C#?

Tags: f#

How do I implement an F# *high order function* in C#?

```
public ICommand RequestAccount = 
    new DelegateCommand(FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc( _ => Debug.WriteLine() ), 
                        FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc( _ => return true       )
                       );
```

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc(Action)' cannot be inferred from the
>   usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Based on the error, I'm not aware of how to express the type parameters explicitly. Hence, I don't think C# understands what a *unit* is that's to be returned on the first lambda.

**DelegateCommand**

```
type DelegateCommand (action:(obj -> unit), canExecute:(obj -> bool)) =
    let event = new DelegateEvent<EventHandler>()
    interface ICommand with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.CanExecuteChanged = event.Publish
        member this.CanExecute arg = canExecute(arg)
        member this.Execute arg = action(arg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in control of both the C# and the F# part of the code, then I would not try to create F# functions explicitly from C# - that will just make your C# code ugly. You can easily add a static method that will take `Func` and `Action` delegates and provide a C#-friendly interface:

```
type DelegateCommand (action:(obj -> unit), canExecute:(obj -> bool)) =
    let event = new DelegateEvent<EventHandler>()
    interface ICommand with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member this.CanExecuteChanged = event.Publish
        member this.CanExecute arg = canExecute(arg)
        member this.Execute arg = action(arg)
    static member Create(action:Action<obj>, canExecute:Func<obj, bool>) = 
        DelegateCommand(action.Invoke, canExecute.Invoke)
```

Now you can use `DelegateCommand.Create` from C# in a nice way:

```
DelegateCommand.Create(
    (o => Console.WriteLine(o)),
    (o => true) )
```

For the record, I also do not quite see the value of defining `DelegateCommand` in F# and using that from C# if you are not doing anything else on the F# side - it seems like a simple type that could as well be defined in C# (i.e. you are not gaining much by doing that in F#).

Comment: For interop between C# and F#, I agree with Tomas--keep the F#-specific types out of APIs that will be used in C#. Action, Func, and delegates are sufficient for passing code blocks around.

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly specify the arguments type

```
public ICommand RequestAccount =
    new DelegateCommand(FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<object>(obj => Debug.WriteLine(obj)),
                        FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<object, bool>(_ => true));
```

Comment: "Using the generic method 'FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<T>(Action<T>)' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: The second lambda have to be: FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc<object, bool>(_ => true) to call the overload ToFSharpFunc<T,U>(Converter<T, U>), see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ee787083(v=vs.120)

Comment: The code snippet just doesn't compile on my machine. Not sure how it can compile on yours but not mine...

Comment: Different F# core version?